# error 200#0: *79 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,

Tags: nginx, php, mac-osx

I want to configure new nginx on my MAC but I got always get `[error] 200#0: *79 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"`.. I don't know what Im doing wrong with config. This is my nginx.conf file:

```
#user  RobDee;
worker_processes  auto;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  #main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

     access_log  logs/access.log;
     error_log  logs/error.log;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  local.mydomain.co.uk local.beer.telegraph.co.uk;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server


   server {
    listen                     443 ;
    server_name                local.mydomain.co.uk local.beer.telegraph.co.uk;

    ssl                        on;
    ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate            /usr/local/etc/nginx/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key        /usr/local/etc/nginx/cert.key;

    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/x-javascript text/css application/json text/javascript;

    access_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;
    log_not_found off;
    root    /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;

    location /.htpasswd
    {
        return 403;
    }
    location ~ \.css {
        root /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;
        expires max;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|js|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
        root /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
        expires 1y;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /
    {
        root /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
         index app_dev.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web/app_dev.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;

    }
    }

    include servers/*;

    }
```

Maybe someone will see some errors in my conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Primary script unknown" almost always means that the value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is wrong.

The problem is likely these three lines:

```
root /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
```

You set the `$document_root`, then hardwire it as `/scripts`. Which is it?

In a normal `nginx` server block, you would set the `root` once near the top of the server block and allow all (or most) `location` blocks to inherit the same value. Only override where necessary. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The usual format for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is either of these:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

Which in your configuration would equate to the same value. Notice that `$document_root` is defined by the value of the `root` directive.

Finally, including `fastcgi_params` last may or may not be ok. In some versions of `fastcgi_params` there may be conflicting definitions for `fastcgi_param` statements you have explicitly defined. You should always include the file before explicit `fastcgi_param` statements.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    root /Users/RobDee/workspace/beer/web;
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
    }
}
```

The `fastcgi_index` directive has no meaning in this context.